# How to access Json dynamically created

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I need to create a simple input words system, where WORDS are nested inside THEMES. The Json file MUST be like structured like this. And the file is dynamically populated. Here´s the Json code:

```
{"TEMAS":
      {
        "FRUTAS": {
          "0": "ABACAXI",
          "1": "JABUTICABA",
          "2": "MEXERICA",
          "3": "GOIABA"
        },
        "CARROS": {
          "0": "FERRARI",
          "1": "FUSCA",
          "2": "HONDA",
          "3": "MERCEDES"
        },
        "BRINQUEDOS": {
          "0": "BOLA",
          "1": "PIÃO",
          "2": "BONECA",
          "3": "CARRINHO",
          "4": "TREM"
        },
        "JOGOS": {
          "0": "XADREZ",
          "1": "VIDEO GAME",
          "2": "FUTEBOL",
          "3": "QUEIMADA"
        }
      }}
```

My application needs to i.e. run inside "FRUTAS" then calculate its length and retrieve its values. Here's my code so far:

```
myApp.controller('catController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('json/word_bank.json')
        .success(function (result) {
          $scope.themes = Object.keys(result.TEMAS);
          var array = Object.keys(result).map(function (key) {
            return result[key];
          });
          console.log(array);
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
          console.log(data);
        });
$scope.category = '';
$scope.words = '';...
```

Someone can help?

Best Regards.

Comment: And what's the problem you have?

Comment: Define problem better and should get plenty of help. Not clear what is or isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for explaining so bad the issue. The stack of my application is like this:
1 - An AngularJS app that takes several word inputs, wich updates a Json file. I cannot work with a database. 
2 - I have to write the Json file with a variable sent by a HTML form.
What is my problem?
Read the Json, copy its data to something (e.g. an array), insert the data inside it, in the correct position. For example, the user write a new word "FOODS" that must enter on the same level as "JOGOS". I must update the json with that word. Then, the user will write another word "RICE" inside "FOOD", like "XADREZ" stands for "JOGOS". But i need the file to be updated, keeping the same structure, words, etc as before plus the new words. Was that clear?
How to do that? I dunno!